# Is this circle always interior to ellipse?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Let $r = a-c$, where $a$ is the length of semi major axis and $c$ is the distance between origin and one of the foci of an ellipse.

I'm wondering if there a nice way to see that the below circle is always interior to the ellipse. 
$$(x-c)^2 + y^2 = r^2$$

I think this is equivalent to saying that the minimum distance between a focus and a point on the ellipse is $a-c$. If so, is there a way to prove this using geometry or some other means ? I feel calculus is messy here... Thank you!

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/il5rpye8on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the semi-minor axis is $b$,
then $c^2 = a^2-b^2$.

For the ellipse,
$(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2 = 1$
or
$y^2
=b^2(1-(x/a)^2)
=b^2-(bx/a)^2
$.

For the circle,

$\begin{array}\\
y^2
&=r^2-(x-c)^2\\
&=(a-c)^2-(x-c)^2\\
&=a^2-2ac+c^2-(x^2-2xc+c^2)\\
&=a^2-2ac-x^2+2xc\\
\end{array}
$

So,
we want to show that
$a^2-2ac-x^2+2xc
\le b^2-(bx/a)^2
$
or
$x^2(1-(b/a)^2)-2xc
\ge a^2-2ac-b^2
$
or
$x^2(c/a)^2-2xc
\ge c^2-2ac
$
or
$x^2(c/a)^2-2xc+a^2
\ge c^2-2ac+a^2
$
or
$(cx/a-a)^2
\ge (c-a)^2
$.

Since
$a \ge c$
and
$x \le a$,
$cx/x \le a$,
so this last is equivalent to
$a-cx/a \ge a-c$
or
$cx/a \le c$
or
$x \le a$,
which is true.

Therefore the circle
*is* always
within the ellipse.

Answer (score 2):

Think to the *gardner-method* to construct the ellipse: then is clear that your circle is the curvature circle at the perihelion (aphelion), and thus internal tangent to the ellipse (by Newton/Kepler laws).

Comment: Internal tangency doesn't guarantee that there's no point of intersection somewhere else, though, without further arguments.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: as a quick argument, I proposed a *Mechanical* argument: the perihelion is by definition the nearest point to the focus=sun, so the curvature circle there (=tangent circle centered at focus) cannot intersect the ellipse in other points.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy to prove using polar coordinates. Move the origin to the focus at $(c,0)$ and rotate so that $\theta=0$ points in the direction of the ellipse’s center. The equation of the ellipse is then $\rho={a(1-e^2)\over1+e\cos\theta}$, where $e$ is the eccentricity of the ellipse. The eccentricity is equal to $c/a$, and substituting this into the above equation produces $$\rho={a(1-(c/a)^2)\over1+(c/a)\cos\theta} = {a^2-c^2\over a+c\cos\theta} \ge {a^2-c^2\over a+c}=a-c.$$ (The denominator on the left side of the inequality is always positive since $a>c$.).

If you want to get fancy, you could construct an argument using the curvature of the ellipse at and away from its intersection with the circle.